# VBA filtering on date turns into US format

Tags: date, excel, vba

I am trying to filter on a date.  Have checked and the control panel knows I am in the UK.  But when I filter it - it has problems and seems to be using the US date format and not the UK.  When you click on the filter it gives the dates / months correctly according to the UK system.

When I recorded the code to see what was happening the following came up.  The date will be defined - I was just trying to figure out what VBA was doing when my filter wouldn't work.

```
Sub dating()


ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AM$442").AutoFilter Field:=38, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, "4/25/2014")
End Sub
```

I have updated the code to and it still won't filter on that date even though there is data with that date in the column.   I am probably missing something obvious here.

```
Dim dteInvoices As Date

dteInvoices = Worksheets("front sheet").Range("f14")

Worksheets("trade details").Range("A1").AutoFilter 39, strText
             .Range("A1").AutoFilter 38, CLng(dteInvoices)
```

Thanks to help from http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/autofilter-vba-dates.htm I have managed to get it to work

http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/autofilter-vba-dates.htm

```
Range("a1").AutoFilter Field:=38, Criteria1:=">=" & lngDate, _
    Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<" & lngDate + 1
```

Comment: Louisa, you have 5 questions and only 1 with an accepted answer. You should accept 1 answer for each question, if you received an acceptable one

Comment: A lot of the questions I have raised have been answered when people have put bits in this comments.  If you looked at my comments I have put what I have done.  I haven't left comments unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

Not a bug. Everywhere in VBA you MUST you US conventions. Which is good: otherwise one would have to use different strings depending on user settings !
I generally use `Format(MyDate, "\#mm\/dd\/yy\#")` to be sure.

Comment: That may be true but VBA is still not consequent from a user's perspective: if you use a Date as parameter, it will convert to String (without the user knowing) using your locale but expect the string to be US locale.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an bug with Excel. The filter does only accept US formatted dates. It makes sense to convert your text to a date using DATEVALUE and then converting the date to a number using CLNG.

Edit: see this thread for a workaround: [Filtering between two dates in pivot table using VBA. UK to US date format issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22938973/3616377)

Comment: When I have done this before I have used double format to filter and it seemed to work.  As double turns it into an integer.  But that didn't seem to work this time.  Will try your way.  Am a bit confused to why its been turned into a string as the dates in excel are definitely in date format and not text.

Comment: I have updated my code and updated the original question with my new code.  It comes up with a value but the filter doesn't accept a value (I have done it with a value on other sheets which works but not this one).

Answer (score 0):

Dates can be tricky with Excel VBA AutoFilter.  Some find it easier to just loop through the array to be filtered.

Sometimes I have found that one can use the numeric value of the date, especially when dealing with "dates between"

```
Criteria2:= CDbl([datecell])
```

or

```
Criteria2:= CLng(Dateserial(2014,4,25))
```

Note that the above need to be "real dates" and not strings that look like dates. Even a single "string date" will mess things up.