# Filtering 7 dates from current date (with missing dates in-between)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a beginner in VBA and I need to code a column wherein I have to un-tick 7 days from the current date. I've been using this code from user LR42

```
    selMonth = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), Day(Date) - 7),   _
                  "m/d/yyyy")

    With Sheet1 '/* change to your actual sheet */
    '/* reference last row to column A */
    lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set myRange = .Range("A1:AY" & lr)
    myRange.AutoFilter 1, "<=" & selMonth
```

It really does un-tick 7 days from my data. However, the problem is sometimes, the data looks like this:

```
Jan 16
Jan 17
Jan 18
Jan 19
Jan 20
**no Jan 21**
Jan 22
**no Jan 23**
Jan 24
```

The date today is January 24. Current date - 7 days is January 18. I want the code to un-tick 7 days (including current date) while considering the fact that there might be missing dates within those dates. If I were to manually un-tick it, I would un-tick it until January 16. However, with the data above, the code would only un-tick until January 18 (while skipping the fact there there's no January 23 and 21).

How should I code it, in such a way that the code would also consider the fact that there might be missing dates within those 7 days?

Comment: Do you mean to untick the last 7 data points (everything in your example)? So if there was Jan 15 also then everything would be unticked except Jan 15?

Comment: Can there be repeat dates? If not, you could order by date and offset by -7 to get the date to use for your condition.

Comment: Yes! Untick last 7 data points. Corrected the current date (should be Jan 24). Yes, everything would be unticked except Jan 15 (considering there are blank dates). No there wouldn't be any repeat dates. How do you code that? I'm a beginner at VBA, sadly

Comment: Would today's date appear? If so, would you untick today's date?

Comment: Yes, I would also untick today's date (Jan. 25) until Jan. 19, given if I am working with data extracted from January 25. The example above was data extracted yesterday.

Comment: Do you mean 19? If Jan 25 was present in data 7 data points would uncheck everything except the 16th

Comment: Are you dd-mm-yyyy time format OR mm-dd-yyyy? Or something else

Comment: Ah yes, if Jan 25 is present, everything would be unchecked except 16th.
My date format is mm-dd-yyyy

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling to test this against a US format of dates but try the following for your settings. Assumes your data is set up as an Excel table called Table1 and that the it has a column called `Date` (in column A), which the sorting is being done on, and that dates are not duplicated.

Note: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> , whilst in a populated cell of your data range, to convert your data range to a table in Excel

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterData()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim sourceTable As ListObject

    Set sourceTable = ws.ListObjects("Table1")

    Dim cutOffDate As Date
    cutOffDate = CDate(ws.Range("A" & Split(Split(sourceTable.DataBodyRange.Address, ":")(1), "$")(2)).Offset(-7, 0).Value2)

    With sourceTable.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[Date]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    sourceTable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<" & cutOffDate, Operator:=xlAnd

End Sub
```

Example data as table:

[image: Data set up for example]

For Non-US date format locales: If you experience problems with different date formats (i.e. not US format) causing the filter to function incorrectly you can try the suggestions by [@Ron Rosenfeld](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23579995/vba-filtering-on-date-turns-into-us-format), basically passing the variable as a Long or Double to avoid the internal conversions:

e.g.

```
Dim cutOffDate As Long
cutOffDate = ws.Range("A" & Split(Split(sourceTable.DataBodyRange.Address, ":")(1), "$")(2)).Offset(-7, 0).Value2
```

Comment: I'm getting **Run-time error 9: Subscript out range** in this line:

Set sourceTable = ws.ListObjects("Table1")

I've used Ctrl + T on my Dates column

Comment: Ahhh. I only used Ctrl + T on the dates column. Now it went past the Set sourceTable line, but I have another error.

**Run-time error 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed**

in the 

.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[Date]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

Comment: Error 1004 is in the:


` .SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[Date]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal`


If it helps, the dates column is in Column A

Comment: It worked now. Changed the myDateColumnName. But it only arranged the dates from oldest to newest. January 24 and backwards are still visible

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I appreciate it so much

Comment: It doesn't really do anything once I get past the cutOffDate = CDate(...)

That's assuming I understood what you said (to run per line, instead of running as a whole?)

Comment: No run the whole sub but just add msgbox cutOffDate before the line With sourceTable.Sort

Comment: A pop-up appears and says 1/24/2018. Afterwards, the same result. Although I think it removed January 24? The last row is now 1/23/2018

Comment: The code orders the date oldest to newest then goes back 7 cells from the last cell and sets that to cutOffDate so I was expecting #1/15/2018# to appear for you. Not #1/24/2018#

Comment: Are the values in the date column actual dates? And are they mm/dd/yyyy formatted as mmm-dd?

Comment: Can you run a test against data set out as per my image just to see if that works?

Comment: I used your code against the data that you provided. The message box popped up and it says **1/15/2018**

Comment: Yes it did. Removed everything except Jan-14

Comment: So we need to determine how you date column differs from my example. If you insert a line msgbox sourceTable.DataBodyRange.Address, ":")(1), "$")(2)).Offset(-7, 0).Address  after Dim cutOffDate As Date what do you get when running the sub?

Comment: Hello! I will respond later as my shift is about to end. Thank you so much for doing this.

Comment: No worries,. Speak later  :-)

Comment: Good day @QHarr ! I pasted the code right after Dim cutOffDate. I got an error though:

Compile error: Expected: end of statement

msgbox sourceTable.DataBodyRange.Address, ":" **)** (1), "$")(2)).Offset(-7, 0).Address

The bold parenthesis is where the highlight should be. I tried inserting/deleting parentheses but I never got to make it work

Comment: My mistake. It should have been ws.Range("A" & Split(Split(sourceTable.DataBodyRange.Address, ":")(1), "$")(2)).Offset(-7, 0).Address    (Apologies). That bit code should be finding the last row of the table in column A.